# Too much information in Django's request.META object

Tags: django, django-request

I've recently been inspecting request.META for a particular view, and it looks to me that all of the environmental variables such as DJANGO_SECRET_KEY, DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME and DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD...etc etc are contained within this object as extra to the default Django `request.META` data. How would I go about remove said variables from the META? Is this in any way accessible from the client side?

I'm guessing I could use some middleware to strip these out, but has anyone else seen this behaviour? Is this normal/safe?

**N.B**. I specify the above as `ENVIRONMENT` variables inside my `docker-compose.yml` file for the django `web` service.

Comment: Why do you care what it contains?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi Daniel, I'm just thinking if someone were to be able inspect the META for malicious intent...(I needed the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header, but technically I can't strip this out so I probably need not worry.)

Comment: Who could inspect it? It's an internal variable. If someone has access to your running Python processes, you have a bigger problem than just what's in a variable.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Fair point.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like because you are setting them as environment variables, they are included in `request.META`. So you would have to look into not actually storing them as env variables, or doing your own processing to customize and remove them. However, note that the client cannot access what is in `request.META`, so it's not bad from a security point of view.

Comment: @NSO I will see if I can accept this is a few others here can verify that it isn't a security issue.

Comment: This is an older answer these days I suppose, but I ran across it today in 2023 as I noticed the same thing when passing/forwarding domain names through NGINX using a proxy pass. Logically this is an internal variable and @DanielRoseman is right. This is not a security issue, if someone can inspect your python runtime, you have someone on your server capable of doing anything